# Custom .htaccess rewrite rules in wordpress not executing

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Issue:

I'd like to be able to modify a url query string parameter for a plugin in wordpress, and take the original url;

*/wp-admin/admin.php?page=espresso_events*

and be able to access it via;

*/wp-admin/admin.php?page=events*

As far as I can tell everything in my .htaccess file is correct, but for some reason it still doesn't work. The rules however look fine, so I cannot understand why wordpress is throwing me an error when I try to access the page via the new url.

This is my .htaccess file;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /event_espresso/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)events(.*)$
RewriteRule . wp-admin/admin.php?%1espresso_events%2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /event_espresso/index.php [L]
```

Using [this](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) online tool, it gives me the correct output url, but when I try the input url directly in wordpress, I just get the same error each time;

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

**Edit:**

This is definitely a wordpress issue. When I manually update my .htaccess file, everything works correctly, however, when using the `mod_rewrite_rules` filter, wordpress doesn't appear to be writing the rule to my .htaccess file, or executing them. I have full write permissions on my .htaccess file.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html - look under troubleshooting, especially, what is AllowOverride set to? (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: @AndreasDuering I don't think this is the issue, as it's set to "AllowOverride All".

Comment: That error message is that coming from Apache or Wordpress?

Comment: @PanamaJack It was coming from Wordpress. I did actually post an answer to this question, but it seems to have vanished. I resolved the problem. I wasn't flushing the access rules properly so Wordpress wasn't updating my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved now. I wasn't flushing the rewrite rules properly via my plugin, so my rewrite rules weren't even being added to the .htaccess file.

```
function plugin_activate()
{
    //make sure rewrite rules are flushed so the htaccess is written to
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_activate');
//actions..
```